# Scattering MC toy model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering, simulations, scattering-cross-section

I would like to make a scattering toy simulation as a computational physics project. I'm having issues visualizing which parameter of the scattering function I need to compare with the randomly generated number to consider that the event was scattered or not.

Using
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \frac{1}{\rho_n t  \Delta \Omega} \frac{\mathrm{Flux_{scattered}}}{\mathrm{Flux_{incident}}}
$$
where $\rho_n$ is the nuclear density of the material that will scatter, $t$ is the thickness, and $\Delta \Omega$ = $4\pi$ since in this toy model the detector will be a sphere around the scattering (and then I won't need to integrate). If I know the total cross-section $\sigma_{tot}$, is it ok to do something like this:

- Generate $N$ random numbers $n_i$
- If $n_i \le 4\pi \sigma_{tot} $ then I had a particle scattered

Comment: Note that $n_i$ is just a unitless number whereas $\sigma$ has units of area, so you can't directly compare them. Try to think about what unitless number you could write down that you'd want to compare with your random numbers.

Comment: Hi @kaylimekay, in this case, in addition to the $4\pi$ multiplication, I would need to multiply the total cross-section by $\rho_n t$ for this comparison hight?

Thank you for your help!